# Mailboxer Trash still receiving in Inbox

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mailboxer

Whenever a user trashes a conversation it is removed from the inbox and is added to the trash.

However, whenever someone else sends a new message to that conversation, it is now in both the trash and the inbox.

I want users to be able to trash the conversation, stop receiving new messages from that conversation, unless they restore said conversation.

So far the inbox view:

```
@conversations = @mailbox.inbox
```

And the trashing action:

```
@conversation.move_to_trash(@user)
```

If anyone has any advice please chime in!

Comment: For the record, I ended up just removing `@conversations` with `.trash?` of `true` in the controller.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it looks like you should manage subscribe/unsubscribe of the recipients.

On trashing:

```
conversation.move_to_trash(current_user)
conversation.unsubscribe(current_user)
```

On restoring:

```
conversation.untrash(current_user)
conversation.subscribe(current_user)
```

Comment: https://github.com/ivoreis/mailboxer/blob/master/app/models/conversation.rb#L95

Comment: This is not the gem's official source, but I'll try to figure something out.

Comment: You are right, it's my bad. Didn't notice, that I was looking through wrong source code.